# trying to scrape website using scrapy-splash

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape javascript website using scrapy-splash but it give me nothing they show these  `<GET https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/countries/uk via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)`  these is the page link https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/countries/uk

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    
    
    def start_requests(self):
        url='https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/countries/uk'
        yield SplashRequest(url)
    
    def parse(self, response):
            books = response.xpath( "//div[@class='card__desc']//a[starts-with(@href, '/online')]//@href").extract()
            for book in books:
                    url = response.urljoin(book)
                    yield{
                        'url':url,
                    }
```

Comment: what operating system are you on?

Comment: what kind of error has been shown? please show the details traceback.

Comment: I have facing no error ..they will not give me any urls